# Matplotlib: subplots' dimensions are not fixed

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is a simplified dashboard made with a single matplotlib plot.

It is refreshed every second. As you can see in this animation, subplot dimensions change slightly according to the **width of y scale text**.

`set_ylimit('label', labelpad=...)` as described at https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel.html sets the pad space for the y label itself, not for the scale text.

`plt.tight_layout(True)` doesn't help too.

**How is it possible to fix the width of the y scale texts?**

[image]

**----------------------------------------------**

**EDIT: After tmdavison and Jody Klimak's comments**

I added `fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.12)`, and removed `tight_layout` and `constrained_layout`.

Now plots have a fixed sizes and subplot sizes don't change anymore, but [A] is "jumping", depending on the scale:

[image]

Is it possible **to set the width of the y labels text**, the yellow rectangle in this pic?

[image]

Comment: Either you are using constrained_layout or tight_layout.  They will change the size of the axes so they are as large as possible.  If you don't want that, then a) don't use those functions, but rather set the axes locations by hand your self b) in the case of constrained_layout, `fig.set_constrained_layout(False)` after the first draw, or c) force the yticks to always include -100 and +100...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the exact positions of the edges of the subplots using [`fig.subplots_adjust()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html).

In this case, you need to set the `left` kwarg to a fixed value and it won't move, no matter how long the `yticklabels` are.

For example:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.12)
```

NB. Make sure you don't use `tight_layout` at the same time, as that may override this setting